# Netbeans 8.1 and Checkstyle plugin

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8, checkstyle

I read in internet that netbeans 7 had checkstyle plugin which helped to fix checkstyle errors. And on this image
[image] from http://marxsoftware.blogspot.ru/2011/08/netbeans-7-and-software-quality.html we see Checkstyle and FindBugs plugins. However, in Netbeans 8.1 I don't see Checkstyle only Findbugs. Can anyone say if it is possible to use checkstyle plugin in Netbeans 8.1 and what must be done for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might just be an error with their compiler catalog. Try downloading it and installing it manually. It's updated for 8.1

Plugin page: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3413/checkstyle-beans